# Lagrangian term for multiple particle interactions in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, interactions

I have the following question. Suppose one wants to describe the dynamics of $N$ interacting classical particles in a metric background given by the line element:
$$ds^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}.$$ For $N$ free particles, the Lagrangian describing each state of any particle can be written as

$$\mathcal{L}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{m_{i}}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{dx_{i}^{\mu}}{d\tau}\dfrac{dx_{i}^{\nu}}{d\tau},$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time. If in addition, the particle $i$ interacts with the other particles $N-1$ via the potential $V_{ij}\sim -Gm_{i}/r_{ij}$ where $r_{ij}$ is the spatial distance from the particle $i$ to the particle $j$. The question is: how does this potential enters in $\mathcal{L}?$ Does it enter as usual in classical mechanics?:
$$\mathcal{L}_{I}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{m_{i}}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\dfrac{dx_{i}^{\mu}}{d\tau}\dfrac{dx_{i}^{\nu}}{d\tau}-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}(1-\delta_{ij})V_{ij}.$$

Comment: What does $M_i$ stand for in the relativistic case? The rest mass of the particles or their total energy? Also, shouldn't there be a metric somewhere to give the distance between the particles?

Comment: @probably_someone yes, $M_{i}=m_{i}$ I just corrected it. The metric is encoded in the $r_{ij}$'s

Comment: This all depends on whether the delays in signal propagation are relevant, that is how much during the time $r_{ij}/c$ does positions of $r_i$ and $r_j$ change? If the position changes in a noticeable way, then one must go from particles to fields or use extended objects (like strings to describe the potentials).

Comment: thanks dear @A.V.S. but there should be a way around to deal with discrete sets of particles, otherwise what are simulations for? Suppose the general case of relativistic particles in a background metric, but locally around each particle, they bend as well spacetime with a specific kind of curvature (example of the potential $V_{ij}$).